# How to read a single data from JSON file in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is my code snippet. It is working fine for loading the data. But when it comes to loading a single data,i am confused about the approach. What is exactly my requirement is that i have to add a button in table header.When i click the button then only it should display my next data else it should it remain as it is. I am new to jQuery. So, it can be a dumb question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         USING AJAX Calls <br> <br> <br>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
                let body = $('#Placeholder').find('tbody');
            $("button").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
                    success: function(data) {
                        data.forEach(d => {
                            body.append(`
                            <tr>
                                <td>${d.id}</td>
                                <td>${d['title']}</td>

                            </tr>`);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        </script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Display Json Placeholder files in tabular format</h1>
            <br>
            <br>
         <!--   <div id="div1"></div>  -->
         <table id="Placeholder" class="display" style="width:100%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
<th>
                        <button id="AppendNextData">Click here to view next data</button>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
         </table>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have to parse that JSON data using JSON.parse() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <!--I have modified your code with your ajax function only you can try, may be this will resolve your issue-->
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
           <head>
              USING AJAX Calls <br> <br> <br>
              <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
              <script>
                 $(document).ready(function() {

                     $("#AppendNextData").click(function(){
                         $.ajax({
                             url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
                             success: function(data) {
                                 var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                                 var tr;
                                 for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                                     tr = $('<tr/>');
                                     tr.append("<td>" + (i+1) + "</td>");
                                     tr.append("<td>" + obj[i].id + "</td>");
                                     tr.append("<td>" + obj[i].title + "</td>");
                                     $('table').append(tr);
                                 }
                             }
                         });
                     });
                 });

            </script>
           </head>
           <body>
              <h1>Display Json Placeholder files in tabular format</h1>
              <br>
              <br>
              <button id="AppendNextData">Click here to view next data</button>
              <table id="table" class="display" style="width:100%" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
                 <tr>
                    <th>Sl No.</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                 </tr>
              </table>
           </body>
        </html>
```